# How can I trigger action back in the react-native from my WebView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I have a component `<PaymentView />`, this component display a credit card/cvc/expiry form.

It is displayed in a react-native application using [`react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/).

I must trigger the form event and update the view on submit, the submit button is currently within the WebView.

- After pressing the submit `<Button />` from within the webview, how can I close the WebView and display a success message?
- If I can't get the webview submit event from within my component, how can I read the form within the webview from my component?

Answer (score 0):

I usually have this problem when dealing with payment iframes in web applications. I think the solution is the same or a similar approach.

Check the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API.

What we usually do, is emit an event on the iFrame (your webView i guess) side. Usually is a navigation event, and then we listen for that event globally in our app like:

```
    <script>

        var defaultResponse = {
            status: 0,
            code: '',
            message: ''
        }

        function queryParamsToObject(search = '') {
            return search ? JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}') : ''
        }

        function getResponseObject() {
            return queryParamsToObject(decodeURI(location.search).substring(1))
        }

        var response = getResponseObject()

        console.log('window:child', window.parent, response)
        try {
            window.parent.postMessage(response, '*')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('window:child:send:error', e)
        }

    </script>
```

On a fast search to `react-native-webview` i see that they are already [using it](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/809)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
  render() {
const html = `
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!")
      }, 2000)
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
`;

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView
      source={{ html }}
      onMessage={event => {
        alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
      }}
    />
  </View>
);
```

}
}